# Best way to implement UILocalNotification for multiple times a day based on user location

Tags: ios, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I have a need in my iOS app to schedule notifications on certain times of the day based on the user's current location.

Time trigger for these notifications are based on a formula that involves user's current location. They are not time triggered exactly on the same time everyday but rather there are slight variations on the exact timings based on where the user is.

How can I implement such a scheduling reliably so it doesn't set the notification at wrong times? How can I fire these notifications automatically without the user launching the app everyday or on certain interval?

Comment: 1. You are getting the current location of the user 2. Then doing some calculation for fire date based on the current location 3. Then scheduling the notification correct?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What have you tried? Where do you have problems?